# Regex for Passport Number

Tags: c#, regex, regex-negation

I am trying to implement regex validation for passport number.

My requirement is

1. Length should be minimum 3 characters to a maximum of 20 characters.
2. Should not be only 0's

I tried with the below regular expression

***^(?!0{3,20})[a-zA-Z0-9]{3,20}$***

This seems to work for most of the cases, but incase my text contains 3 or more leading zeros, it seems to fail. Such as '00000001'.

Example Matches

- 101AE24 - Working as expected
- 00 - Not working as expected
- 01234 - Working as expected
- **00001 - Not working (But it should also be match)**

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Does it have to be a regex? You could solve this by first checking the length, then making sure you had at least 1 or more of the following `[A-Za-z1-9]`

Comment: for length ^[0-9]{3,20}$ and then check Convet.ToInt32(value) == 0

Comment: @viveknuna String can have alpha chars.

Comment: then use [a-zA-Z0-9] simple and int.TryParse

Answer (score 14, accepted):

What about this?

```
^(?!^0+$)[a-zA-Z0-9]{3,20}$
```

Instead of saying 'reject values with 3-20 zeros', we can just say 'reject anything that *only* contains zeros (regardless of the length, since <3 and >20 fail anyway)

Comment: Hello
I want to validate passport numbers for all countries. And I want to have a list of regex for every country, Something like this: https://github.com/validatorjs/validator.js/blob/master/src/lib/isPassportNumber.js#L9
 
But it is not complete. do you have a complete list?

Answer (score 1):

It took me around 5 minutes to learn Regex online [iOS, Swift]. Here is my a simple answer to understand for beginners.

For 1 Alphabet & 7 digits:

```
[A-Z]{1}[0-9]{7}
```

For 2 Alphabets & 7 digits:

```
[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{7}
```

--

```
func validatePassport(from value: String?) throws {
    guard let passportNo = value, !passportNo.isEmpty else {
        throw MyError.noPassport
    }
    let PASSPORT_REG_EX = "[A-Z]{1}[0-9]{7}"
    let passport = NSPredicate(format:"SELF MATCHES %@", PASSPORT_REG_EX)

    if !passport.evaluate(with: passportNo) {
        throw MyError.invalidPassport
    }
}
```

Comment: The passport number can also be numeric only, for example, mine contains 8 numbers. The pattern which is quite good is ^(?!(0))[a-zA-Z0-9]{6,9}$ - cannot start with 0, and contains 6-9 alphanumeric characters. I however believe that there can only be 1 or 2 letter at the beginning which would make it an even more complex pattern.

Answer (score 1):

I saw this expression from [this link](http://www.regexlib.com/REDetails.aspx?regexp_id=2392&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1)

```
^[A-Z0-9<]{9}[0-9]{1}[A-Z]{3}[0-9]{7}[A-Z]{1}[0-9]{7}[A-Z0-9<]{14}[0-9]{2}$
```

Comment: This regex is valid for Sri Lankan passports.

Answer (score 0):

`*r'^[a-zA-Z0-9]{3,20}$'*`  Use This Expression

This regular expression is designed to match strings that:

- Start and end with the specified characters (^ and $).
- Contain only alphanumeric characters (letters A-Z, a-z, and digits 0-9).
- Are between 3 and 20 characters in length.